# when tapped notification willPresent notification: is not called

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, swift5

I'm using UNNotificationExtension and after using it the remote call function is never called.
I'm trying to get the data whenever notification is tapped.

```
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
   
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                        didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                        withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler()
    }
```

the call to this function is never received.
What i can do so i can get data whenever user clicks the notification either foreground or background.

Answer (score 0):

As no information is given regarding whether `didReceive(_:withContentHandler:)` method which is present inside Notification extension folder is called or not in your case, I presume it is not getting called. As that method needs to be handled correctly inorder to execute  `userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,didReceive: ..` method.

Once remote notification for your app is received, the system loads your extension and calls its `didReceive(_:withContentHandler:)` method only when both of the following conditions are met:

- The remote notification is configured to display an alert.
- Remote notification’s payload includes the mutable-content key with
  the value set to 1.

And call the contentHandler closure with passing the bestAttemptContent. Once this is done the  `userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,didReceive` response will be called.